# Is there a product operator (or work around) in SQLite?

Tags: r, sqlite, aggregate, product

I am using `GROUP BY` to aggregate over an item per month. I would like the `SUM` of one column and the product of another. I can't find a product operator online or in my book... but is there a series of other operators that will build the product operator?

In a pinch, I can do the product operating in R, which is where the data are heading, but I would love to minimize the amount of looping I do.

Thanks!

Update: OK, so I really wanted to create a product aggregator to send the product of a column back to R. In trying to answer a futerh downstream question I got the answer that put it all together. There's already a library of common functions not incorporated into SQLite (the [Healey functions](http://www.sqlite.org/contrib//download/extension-functions.c?get=25)). I can easily use these functions in R using a library ([RSQLite.extfuns](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite.extfuns/index.html)). So I can create the product aggregator by exponentiating the sum of logs. Thanks to DWin for [showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173019/load-macports-sqlite3-when-using-rsqlite-library) me the key piece about the RQLite.extfuns library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own aggregate operator using [create_function().](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)

Comment: OK, newbie questions... Where do I save the C func? What do I call it? Do I have to compile? My googling and book assume that I know the housekeeping aspects of C and the SQLite API. Thanks!

Comment: create_function is just a function call, but the functions that you must pass to it to implement your aggregate function are functions you must write and compile.  "The seventh, eighth and ninth parameters, xFunc, xStep and xFinal, are pointers to C-language functions that implement the SQL function or aggregate. A scalar SQL function requires an implementation of the xFunc callback only; NULL pointers must be passed as the xStep and xFinal parameters. An aggregate SQL function requires an implementation of xStep and xFinal and NULL pointer must be passed for xFunc."

Answer (score 2):

If the number of rows per group is small enough, you might use [`group-concat`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) to return all the multiplicands for R.

Comment: This will come in handy, too. Thanks!