# Load MacPorts SQLite3 when using RSQLite library

Tags: r, macports

I have a user defined function in SQLite (an aggregator that calculates the product) and it works fine outside R. But I'm on a Mac some of the time, which requires the MacPorts version of SQLite3 if you'd like to add your own functions/extensions.

Can I pick which SQLite3 that RSQLite loads? I don't see anything in the SQLite documentation.

Also, MacPorts appears to change my `sqlite3` link to the MacPorts installed SQLite3:

```
mbp:~ richard$ which sqlite3
/opt/local/bin/sqlite3
```

But if I want to load the extension in SQLite3, I have to explicitly can the MacPorts version, like this:

```
mbp:~ richard$ /opt/local/bin/sqlite3 temp.sqlite
```

Is writing my own SQLite functions and combining them with R a lost cause? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed and loaded the RSQLite.extfuns package? It has a single function which loads the available functions:

```
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = ":memory:")
init_extensions(db)
```

By default these are the [Healy extensions](http://www.sqlite.org/contrib//download/extension-functions.c?get=25).

Comment: HUGE! I want those ten hours back trying to learn C and messing around with MacPorts. I built a product aggregator, but I can create it with `exp(sum(log(col_x)))'. Thanks!